# How to split url from specific point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url such as:
http://www.mysite.com/page/blog/category/postname/

What I need to do is split it from the third to last '/', so it returns:
category/postname/

How do I do this????

Comment: Is the URL always the same length at the beginning? Do you always want what's after the blog/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var last3 = str.split("/").slice(-3).join("/");
```